# C# Word VSTO: Generate a word document in "background" as file?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm filling a word document with data of a db.

Now I'm using `this.Application.Documents.Add();`
to get a Word.Document Object and manipulate it.
This object is shown in the Word instance.

The issue is to get a Word.Document Object, which I can manipulate
and save in **background**.

So after the dataprocessing is done, I can
open it in the Word instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documents.Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.add.aspx) function has an optional parameter named `Visible`. You can pass false to this argument and your document will not be shown in the Word instance. You can still manipulate this document through code just like normal documents. After you're done with your stuff, call `Document.Save()` to save it to disk. Thereupon you can open it in visible mode as and when needed.